# How to cast from `std::vector<uint8_t>` to `std::vector<int8_t>`?

Tags: c++, casting

I need to fill data into SetByteArrayRegion:

```
void JNIEnv::SetByteArrayRegion(jbyteArray array, jsize start, jsize len, const jbyte *buf)
```

where `jbyte` is simply `int8_t`. I have a vector of `uint8_t`. Why I cannot cast it to a vector of `int8_t`? `uint8_t` and `int8_t` have the same size so they could be casted easily.

```
std::vector<uint8_t> messageResponseVector_ = //...
std::vector<int8_t> messageResponseVector = static_cast<std::vector<int8_t>>(messageResponseVector_);//does not work
```

What is best to do in this situation? I receive the vector as `std::vector<uint8_t>`. I could convert easily to `std::vector<int8_t>` with a for loop but is there an easier way?

Comment: `std::vector<uint8_t>` and `std::vector<int8_t>` are completely different types.  You cannot treat one as he other.

Comment: You can't cast vectors.    You can copy elements, and cast/convert the elements when copying.    `std::copy()` can do that without fuss, since there is an implicit conversion from `uint8_t` to `int8_t`.    And you can't simply declare `messageResponseVector` as one type and coerce it to take on another type.

Comment: @Peter There is an implicit conversion from `uint8_t` to `int8_t`, but for values exceeding 127 the result is implementation-defined. It's very very likely to be what you'd expect (for example 255 --> -1), but it's not guaranteed. It's likely that any implementation where `JNIEnv` exists won't be exotic enough to do anything other than what you'd expect.

Comment: @KeithThompson   Yep.   As I said there is an implicit conversion.   I didn't say there is an implicit conversion that always give the intended effect, because the OP has not specified what effect is intended in doing that conversion.

Comment: @Peter On the other hand, the fact that the OP didn't mention that probably implies that it's something they need to know. Guerlando: What do you want the result of the conversion to be? If you have a `uint8_t` element with a value of 255, that's outside the range of `int8_t`. You *probably* want `-1` in that case, but you should be explicit about your requirements.

Comment: @KeithThompson - Frankly, that is small potatoes.   The fact that the OP is seeking to type cast containers as an alternative to copying elements from one container to another is a bigger concern.   Type casting has its place, but is most often a dangerous last resort to address significant problems that often cannot be sanely addressed in other ways.   Trying to cast containers is missing the point entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast a `vector<uint8_t>` to a `vector<int8_t>`, they are completely separately and unrelated types.  But, you can cast the *data* instead, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<uint8_t> messageResponseVector_ = //...
jbyte *data = reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(messageResponseVector_.data());
env->SetByteArrayRegion(array, 0, messageResponseVector_.size(), data);
```

Though, *technically* this is undefined behavior, due to **strict aliasing** rules.  The *safer* option is to simply copy the data into a separate `vector<jbyte>`, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<uint8_t> messageResponseVector_ = //...
std::vector<jbyte> messageResponseVector2_(messageResponseVector_.begin(), messageResponseVector_.end());
jbyte *data = messageResponseVector2_.data();
env->SetByteArrayRegion(array, 0, messageResponseVector2_.size(), data);
```

Otherwise, see if you can change your code to receive `messageResponseVector_` as a `vector<int8_t>` (if not `vector<jbyte>`) to begin with:

```cpp
std::vector<int8_t> messageResponseVector_ = //...
jbyte *data = reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(messageResponseVector_.data());
env->SetByteArrayRegion(array, 0, messageResponseVector2_.size(), data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int foo() {
    std::vector<uint8_t> messageResponseVector_;
    std::vector<int8_t> messageResponseVector2(messageResponseVector_.begin(), messageResponseVector_.end());
}
```

Comment: The initialization of `messageResponseVector2` can be simplifed to `std::vector<int8_t> messageResponseVector2(messageResponseVector_.begin(), messageResponseVector_.end());` No need to construct and resize it first and then copy into it separately. The constructor can handle everything in one go.

Comment: @RemyLebeau mybad, hadn't even thought of that

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.